# Getting Null value on using AddMember in rapidjson

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to create json string using RapidJson and VC++. Below is my code:

```
WDocument saveDoc; 
WValue settingDoc(kObjectType);
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_ID",  "456723", saveDoc.GetAllocator());
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_FOUND",  true, saveDoc.GetAllocator());
WValue wImplVal;
wImplVal.SetString(BookName, saveDoc.GetAllocator()); //TCHAR BookName[MAX_PATH]
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_NAME",  wImplVal, saveDoc.GetAllocator());     //gets correct book name
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_NICK_NAME",wImplVal,saveDoc.GetAllocator());//gets null value in wImplVal 
saveDoc.SetObject();    
saveDoc.AddMember("BOOK_INFO", settingDoc, saveDoc.GetAllocator());
```

I am getting NULL value second time, on using wImplVal even though I have not modified it.
Do we have some special rules for adding one value in two keys in rapidjson.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you read [this](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html) carefully, especially "Move semantics" section you can figure out that rapidjson values uses, well, move semantics, so when you pass it to `AddMember`, it moves out existing value and replaces it with `Null`.

> As RapidJSON supports C++03, it adopts move semantics using assignment operator, and all other modifying function like AddMember(), PushBack().

So your have to set value again to get what you want.

```
WDocument saveDoc; 
WValue settingDoc(kObjectType);
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_ID",  "456723", saveDoc.GetAllocator());
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_FOUND",  true, saveDoc.GetAllocator());
WValue wImplVal;
wImplVal.SetString(BookName, saveDoc.GetAllocator()); //TCHAR BookName[MAX_PATH]
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_NAME",  wImplVal, saveDoc.GetAllocator());     //gets correct book name
wImplVal.SetString(BookName, saveDoc.GetAllocator());
settingDoc.AddMember("BOOK_NICK_NAME",wImplVal,saveDoc.GetAllocator());//gets null value in wImplVal 
saveDoc.SetObject();    
saveDoc.AddMember("BOOK_INFO", settingDoc, saveDoc.GetAllocator());
```